# C# list of substitutable type

Tags: c#, types

I have following structure:

```
awesomeItemBase
+ int a
+ int b

awesomeItemSpecial1: awesomeItemBase
+ int c
+ string s
..etc

awesomeItemSpecial2: awesomeItemBase
+ int d
+ string t
..etc
```

Let's assume I want to create a list of those 2 derived classes by wrapping them in one common type, so that each list item holds the information ***int a, int b***
An interface cannot have fields..

How could I do this?

Comment: why not using properties ? Interface can use them

Comment: "How could I do this?" -- You already did it, didn't you? `List<awesomeItemBase>` populated with `awesomeItemSpecial1` and `awesomeItemSpecial2` elements (casted to `awesomeItemBase`) will allow you to iterate that list and access the `a` and `b` properties of each item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you could do this:

```
public class AwesomeItemBase {
    // you could also make these fields
    public int A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;}
}

public class AwesomeItemSpecial1 : AwesomeItemBase {
    // additional fields and properties
}

public class AwesomeItemSpecial2 : AwesomeItemBase {
    // additional fields and properties
}
```

You'd then be able to:

```
var foo = new AwesomeItemSpecial1();
foo.A = 42;
foo.B = -1;
var bar = new AwesomeItemSpecial2();
bar.A = 3;
bar.B = 59;

var awesomeList = new List<AwesomeItemBase>();
awesomeList.Add(foo);
awesomeList.Add(bar);

foreach (var item in awesomeList) {
    Console.WriteLine("A = {0}, B = {1}", item.A, item.B);
}

// output is:
// A = 42, B = -1
// A = 3, B = 59
```

Comment: AwesomeItemBase  can be even an interface not necesary a class. Apart from that - I agree.

Comment: @Vladimir If `AwesomeItemBase` is an interface then the two "Special" classes would have to implement the `A` and `B` properties individually.  Whether to make `AwesomeItemBase` an interface, abstract class, or class would depend on the use case.